# Spell check with formula or apps script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas

I have text in the table. I want to check the text whether there is a typo or not. Usually to check my typo using the default Spelling Tool from Google Sheet.

[image]

The question is: Can the spelling check be changed to a formula, for example, I type the formula on Cell B3?

```
= SpelCheck (A2)
```

When entering, the correct word suggestion [image: results out].

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AC3kBLJ6rDEgZxJirV5Nq5zN9pKLCj1FNW2UZA9Q6sY/edit#gid=0)

Comment: sheet is private

Answer (score 1):

There isn't formula which would correct spelling of value in the cell. Closest you can get is to use **`DETECTLANGUAGE`** formula and check if the cell's content is valid grammatically. Something like:

```
=DETECTLANGUAGE(A3)
```

[image]

which can be then a bit improoved to:

```
=IF(DETECTLANGUAGE(A3)="en", "ok", "spelling error")
```

[image]